# bootstrap-table-filter-control options sorting

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

Using Boostrap table by whenzhixin with filter-control extension.
http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/#table-filter-control

I would like the options display in the select to be sorted in numerical order.

Code is available at: https://jsfiddle.net/yd75psoc/4

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>

<table
    id="table"
    data-filter-control="true"
    data-filter-show-clear="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">ID</th>
            <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
            <th data-field="price" data-filter-control="select">Item Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<script>
    var $table = $('#table')

    $(function() {
        var data = [
            {
                'id': 0,
                'name': 'Item 0',
                'price': '$10'
            },
            {
                'id': 1,
                'name': 'Item 1',
                'price': '$1'
            },
            {
                'id': 2,
                'name': 'Item 2',
                'price': '$2'
            }
        ]
        $table.bootstrapTable({data: data})
    })
</script>
```

You will see that options are shown in the following order: 1, 10, 2. 
[current behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FHaQ.png)

I need these values to be displayed in numerical order: 1, 2, 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the `filter-control` version you are using.

I have edited you code and it's working with the `filter-control` version that i'm using.

edited fiddle: `https://jsfiddle.net/eitanmg/0y3tp4n7/1/`

filter-control version that i'm using (and solved you problem):

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eitanmg/bootstrap-table-filter-control/master/bootstrap-table-filter-control.js

just replace this library with yours and you should be fine.

Comment: Your library works as I would expect, thanks! I have raised a ticket to allow them to fix the bug: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/4353

Comment: great, you can also add this SO thread to the github ticket too.

Comment: Done, cross-referenced now.

Answer (score 0):

Using boostrap-table and upgrading from 1.18.3 to 1.22.1.
I think problem is not fixed:

I've just tried on same example but with name:

Item Name
and changed names.

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/develop/src/bootstrap-table.js" type="module"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/develop/src/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.js" type="module"></script>


<table id="table" data-filter-control="true" data-filter-show-clear="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">ID</th>
      <th data-field="name"  data-filter-control="select">Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-filter-control="select">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>


    var $table = $('#table')

$(function() {
  var data = [{
      'id': 0,
      'name': 'Item D',
      'price': '10'
    },
    {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'Item B',
      'price': '1'
    },
    {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'Item A',
      'price': '2'
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'Item C',
      'price': '20'
    }
  ]
  $table.bootstrapTable({
    data: data
  })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gm3f95ks/6/

Alphabetical order is not fixed.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35352699)